# powershell passwordlastset export to spread sheet

Tags: powershell, csv

Why is this coming up blank for all machines in the passwordlastset attribute, when I export it in the csv file?  Everything else works perfectly.

```
 $Searcher = New-ObjectSystem.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher([ADSI]"LDAP://dc=amers,dc=jhe,dc=domain,dc=com")

 $Searcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=computer)(objectClass=computer)(!UserAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)(operatingSystem=Windows XP*))"

 $Searcher.PageSize = 100000

 $results = $Searcher.Findall()

 $results | ForEach-Object { $_.GetDirectoryEntry() } |
 select @{ n = 'CN'; e = { ($_.CN) } },
   @{ n = 'DistinguishedName'; e = { $_.DistinguishedName } },
   @{ n = 'extensionattribute7'; e = { $_.extensionattribute7 } },
   @{ n = 'LastLogon'; e = { [DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.PasswordLastSet) } },
   @{ n = 'OperatingSystem'; e = { $_.OperatingSystem } } |
 Export-Csv 'C:\temp\WindowsXP_Only.csv' -NoType -Force
```

Comment: How are you getting data into `$results`?

Comment: Try `$Searcher.SearchScope = 'Subtree'` before you call `FindAll()`.  Possibly also `$Searcher.SearchBase = [ADSI]"LDAP://dc=amers,dc=jhe,dc=domain,dc=com"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default not all properties are returned, so you need to specify the additional properties you want.

Also, if you're looking for the last logon date (per your output), you should be using `lastLogonTimestamp` and not `PasswordLastSet`.

Here's an example using `Get-ADComputer`, which I greatly prefer over using older methods of searching AD. Just add your `Export-CSV` when you're happy with the results.

```
$results = get-adcomputer -Filter "operatingSystem -like 'Windows XP*'" -properties cn,lastlogontimestamp,operatingsystem,extensionattribute7,PasswordLastSet -searchbase "dc=amers,dc=jhe,dc=domain,dc=com";
$results | 
 select @{ n = 'CN'; e = { ($_.cn) } },
   @{ n = 'DistinguishedName'; e = { $_.DistinguishedName } },
   @{ n = 'extensionattribute7'; e = { $_.extensionattribute7 } },
   @{ n = 'LastLogon'; e = { [DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.lastLogonTimestamp) } },
   @{ n = 'PasswordLastSet'; e = { [DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.PasswordLastSet) } },
   @{ n = 'OperatingSystem'; e = { $_.OperatingSystem } }
```

You might also find [this script useful](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-Inactive-Computer-in-54feafde)